# Strange execution time for recursive grep

Tags: performance, grep

I'm on a Linux Ubuntu machine, grepping a large number of files. Can anyone explain these timings?

```
>time grep -nIr acct_margin *
[... 3 results ...]
real    0m0.555s
user    0m0.400s
sys     0m0.150s
```

Case insensitive:

```
>time grep -niIr acct_margin *
[... 3 results ...]

real    0m45.739s
user    0m45.300s
sys     0m0.240s
```

With an "or" operator in the regex:

```
>time grep -nIr "acct_margin\|MARGIN_TABLE" *
[... 5 results ...]

real    0m15.892s
user    0m15.540s
sys     0m0.260s
```

Case insensitive:

```
>time grep -niIr "acct_margin\|MARGIN_TABLE" *
[... 5 results ...]

real    0m52.433s
user    0m52.050s
sys     0m0.200s
```

I've run the commands enough that the files should be cached (`htop` confirms open ram space).

Case insensitivity incurs a factor of nearly 100x slower? That should be a constant time increase in amount of processing. Pipe operator a factor of 30x slower? I guess I can't argue with the results, but I'm just curious how one writes grep such that it performs this way, and if there's any way around it. High performance grep, anyone?

Comment: Do the files contain Unicode or plain ASCII characters?

Comment: plain ASCII. Mostly C++ files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Case insensitivity incurs a factor of nearly 100x slower? That should be a constant time increase in amount of processing.

Well, no. For starters, there are 1024 different strings that match *acct_margin* with the `-i` switch.

Matching *acct_margin* is case sensitively easy; if the current character isn't an *a*, skip. With case-folding, you have to check if the current character is an *a* or an *A*. That's not only two tests, you also have a lot more matches you can't skip directly.<sup>1</sup> It gets more difficult for non-ASCII characters.

Nevertheless, `grep -i` shouldn't be so slow. This seems to be bad implementation of case-folding when multi-byte characters are anticipated (even though none are present in the files).

#### Possible workarounds

1. Do not use the `-i` switch and construct the case-insensitive regular expression by hand.
2. If the files contain only ASCII characters, temporarily set the encoding identifier of the environment variable *LANG* to *ISO-8859-1* (a.k.a. Western European, Latin-1 or Code Page 819).
3. Select one of the non-default regular expression types (`--fixed-strings`, `--extended-regexp` or `--perl-regexp`).
4. If the files contain only ASCII characters and case-folding the *output* is admissible, do not use the `-i` switch and pipe case-folded characters to grep.

#### Test setup

I've created a 500 MB file of Base64-encoded pseudo-random bytes on my computer<sup>2</sup>, killed all CPU- or memory-intensive processes and compared the execution times of the above workarounds to a plain `grep` or `grep -i`.

I've fed the input file to grep and tr using a redirector and discarded the output to eliminate potential sources of bias.

I've run every command several times; the execution times were stable (maximum variation of ±0.01s).

#### Bechmarks

```
$ # Make time output only elapsed time:
$ TIME="  %es"
$ # C create 500MB file of 76 printable ASCII characters per line:
$ < /dev/urandom base64 | head -c 500MB > file
$ # Verify that current character encoding is UTF8:
$ echo "  $LANG"
  en_US.UTF-8
# Benchmark of case-sensitive `grep' for comparison:
$ < file time grep test > /dev/null
  0.45s
$ # Benchmark of case-sensitive `grep --perl-regexp' for comparison:
$ < file time grep -P test > /dev/null
  0.82s
$ # Benchmark of case-insensitive `grep' for comparison:
$ < file time grep -i test > /dev/null
  21.08s
$ # Workaround 1:
$ < file time grep [Tt][Ee][Ss][Tt] > /dev/null
  1.53s
$ # Workaround 2:
$ (LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1; < file time grep -i test > /dev/null)
  1.53s
$ # Workaround 3:
$ < file time grep -Pi test > /dev/null
  1.33s
$ # Workarounds 2 and 3 combined:
$ (LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1; < file time grep -Pi test > /dev/null)
  1.25s
$ # Workarounds 4:
$ < file time tr [A-Z] [a-z] | grep test > /dev/null
  0.46s
```

There was no measurable difference between the default and the other non-default regular expression types.

There was no measurable difference between the last version of grep from the standard Ubuntu repositories (2.10) and the latest stable version of GNU grep (2.14).

#### Conclusions

- Workaround 1 and 2 result in the same speed-up.

  This suggests that workaround 1 is similar to how grep's case-folding works when no multi-byte characters are anticipated.
- While `--perl-regexp` is a lot slower for case-sensitive matching, it's magnitudes faster for case-insentive matching.
- `--perl-regexp` becomes even faster if no multi-byte characters are anticipated.
- At the expense of case-folding the output, workaround 4 can be as fast as case-sensitive matching.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm not suggesting that this is how grep works internally. THis is emant to illustrate why case-insensitive matching is more complicated.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Intel Core i5-3570K, 16 GiB RAM, Ubuntu 12.10</sub>

Comment: Dennis, `grep -i` should NOT be that much slower if it's coded right.  My own `grep` runs imperceptibly slower with `-i` and always faster than the Cygwin `grep`.  For example, on just over 89KLOC of C, here were the times to search for "include" on my Win7 core i7 machine:  My `grep` 0.03s with/without `-i`.  Cygwin `grep` 0.09s, Cygwin `grep -i` 0.16s.

Comment: Bug/bad implementation was actually my first guess, especially since Ubuntu's grep is over a year old.

Comment: They've probably chosen a poor compilation scheme which then doesn't execute well.  (I deliberately don't read GNU code so as to ensure no GNU code or ideas creep into my own code.  So I don't know our algorithms compare internally.)  But I don't think the problem is year-old code.  `grep` has been around for decades and should be really stable.  I haven't touched the source for my own `grep` for 4 years and that was for something unrelated to my regex.  I probably haven't changed my regex in about a decade.

Comment: Exactly: *should* run stable. It's been almost seven years now since GNU's Wget hangs indefinitely when an HTTPS connection times out ([bug #385506](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi))...

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: You were right. I've tried the latest stable version of grep; it made no difference.